# UILabel LineBreakMethod

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, line-breaks

I tried to break a label according to the text that contains. The code is below:

```
mnhmeioLabel.numberOfLines=0;
mnhmeioLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[mnhmeioLabel sizeToFit];
```

Although it seems to work only sometimes. I added a snapshot of my problem and what i want.[image]

The problem is in red box that breaks the line with a way that i cannot understand. The result that i want is in the yellow box.

Comment: make sure that you are not giving so much space between words

Comment: check that you always call `[mnhmeioLabel sizeToFit]` just after setting the text

Comment: @slecorne I always do this after setting the text.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra how can i check this? Text is read from json file and is fixed.

Comment: Please check Json text at your end by printing NSLOg

Comment: @AshutoshMishra I have already printed that and all of my text that i pass to labels have the same space between words.

Comment: Please use NSLOg on length of string too

Comment: @AshutoshMishra lengths are correct too.

Comment: are you updating length of each row at run time of it is previously fixed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first YouShould get label Height base on text

```
UILabel *mnhmeioLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:giveYourframe];
[mnhmeioLabel setText:heregiveYourText]
mnhmeioLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    // get height base on label text and size
CGFloat height=[self getStringHeightforLabel:mnhmeioLabel];
    //set fram after getting height  

cell.mnhmeioLabel.frame=CGRectMake(cell.mnhmeioLabel.frame.origin.x,cell.mnhmeioLabel.frame.origin.y,cell.mnhmeioLabel.frame.size.height,height);


[cell.mnhmeioLabel sizeToFit];
```

// call  this  to get height

```
-(CGFloat)getStringHeightforLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width,9999);
CGSize stringSize= [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
                              constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                  lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
return stringSize.height;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there might be a space in the text that is coming from json.

Try this:

```
      NSString * jsonAfterOmittingSpace=[jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "  withString:@""];
```

and then put this string on label

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your label width is changing at runtime. use a Fixed width/height  for your UILabel

Comment: Label is in a tableview cell and it has fixed width and height.

Comment: NSLog your width and height of label and check in cellForRowAtIndexPath:.. from image it seems like width of the label is changing somehow..